# COM port problem when uploading bootloader to SAMD21G

Tags: bootloader

I use an ATSAMD21E16B-AU in my circuit and I want to upload the bootloader with the SAM-BA flash programming tool in this official link:
http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-42366-SAM-BA-Bootloader-for-SAM-D21_ApplicationNote_AT07175.pdf.

I will use that directly with USB cable signals D+, D-, 5V, GND (SAMD microprocessor has internal USB serial hardware and D+ D- pins)

Before I try to upload it, it needs to appear in Device Manager on Windows as a "COM port" with EDBG driver. Because it didn't, SAM-BA doesn't show any COM port as EDBG in the "Select the connection" section.

Can I burn a bootloader to ATSAMD without an JTAG device? For example, I want learn if I can do that with Arduino Zero?

Comment: External condition: Reset the part and make sure the Hardware Bootloader Entry pin (PA15) is pulled low
when reset is released.  e.g. push button then apply power.